# How to plot Classification Report?

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn

Here's my code, How to plot classification report? I have looked all the other posts here, but most of them are plotting the confusion matrix not classification report, Can anyone help me plot classification report?

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

import matplotlib as mpl

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, matthews_corrcoef, confusion_matrix


target = ['-1', '1', '0']

X = alldata["data"]

y= alldata["SentimentIntensityAnalyzer"]

count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')

transformer = TfidfTransformer(norm='l2',sublinear_tf=True)

from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, KFold

kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train_index], X[test_index], y[train_index], y[test_index]

X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)

X_train_tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

x_test_counts = count_vect.transform(X_test)

x_test_tfidf = transformer.transform(x_test_counts)

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)

y_score = clf.predict(x_test_tfidf)

print('Multinomial NB with TextBlob',accuracy_score(y_test,y_score))

report1 = classification_report(y_score, y_test, target_names=target, digits=4)

print(report1)
```

here is the output , what i want is to plot precison , recall and f1-score ( The whole Classification report not confusion matrix.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by plotting ? given that each metric is just simple scalar

Comment: @Alka , I need the plot which compares all these outputs in a single graph so that i can use that in my thesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier way might be creating a dataframe from the classification report output and then simply calling the `plot` method in pandas DataFrame.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn import datasets
from IPython import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

target = ['-1', '1', '0']


X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_classes=3, n_informative=5,)
X[X < 0] = 0

kf = model_selection.StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train_index], X[test_index], y[train_index], y[test_index]
    clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_score = clf.predict(X_test)
    print('Multinomial NB with TextBlob',accuracy_score(y_test,y_score))

    report1 = classification_report(y_score, y_test, target_names=target, digits=4,  output_dict=True)

    display.display(pd.DataFrame(report1))
    df = pd.DataFrame(report1)
    df.iloc[:3, :3].T.plot(kind='bar')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
from IPython import display
import pandas as pd

#dim representes the number of classes, here we have 10
target = np.array([*range(0, dim, 1)])

#Where, for example
#y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
#y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
#target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2',
# 'class 3', 'class 4', 'class 5', 'class 6', 'class 7', 'class 8', 'class 9']

report1 = classification_report(flat_true, flat_pred, target_names=target, 
digits=4,  output_dict=True)

display.display(pd.DataFrame(report1))
df = pd.DataFrame(report1)

#Where 3 represents 3  bars for precision, recall, and F1-score
#and 10 represents the Ten classes

df.iloc[:3, :10].T.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```